# How does Google search PDF's so quickly even though it takes way more time for the PDF to load when I open the link?

Tags: search, google-search

It takes time for the PDF load completely when I click on links in Google. But Google searches millions of files and returns the exact result. It even returns part where words I searched can be found(briefly below the result). All of this in a few seconds.

However it takes way more time to open those links individually.

MY REASONING- Google has already gone through the internet(as soon as the link is uploaded to net) and Google just gives me links from its history rather doing the search in real time.

But still it sounds unconvincing as it might make it slightly quick but not much.

Also as an extension, can solution to this be used as hack to open web-pages / PDF quickly avoiding all irrelevant parts(like ads/toolbars in some news pages etc)? You know if Google can search it in such short time, there should be a way for us to get relevant pages quickly,right?
Thanks in advance.

[Example: Image of the PDF which took over 10s to open. But Google returned the result in 0.58s(according Google itself)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ly5C.png)

Comment: indexing happens ahead of time, so that your query is answered by the reverse index of words / phrases mapping to the document's URL, never by opening the document and scanning it as a result of the query.

Comment: Web search engines do not search "the internet" to answer your queries; they search their indexes (think huge databases containing the words extracted from web pages), which they have built with great effort over a long time, and which they keep up to date using a variety of strategies.

Comment: @diginoise  But they give info about what's inside a PDF. See the pic I added. How do they do that? By info I don't mean just title. In the pic you can see it is giving keywords which is in the index part with searched words highlighted. That too index in exact order(not just keywords)

Comment: @AlexP See my above comment.(I couldn't tag 2 people)

Comment: They index the web-accessible documents. That means that they have a program, called a spider or [web crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler), which goes and reads each and every page and document it finds by following links from a set of seed pages. They store the text read by the spider in their huge databases. When you put a query they search their databases and return the results. When you click on a result your browser goes and fetches a fresh copy of the page from the original server; it may be the same as what the search engine had in its database, it may be different...

Comment: @AlexP Thanks. Can you also please answer the last part(extension part) of my question? Is that possible in any way?

Comment: The ads, etc. are not part of the web page. They are brought in from third party servers. Even if you open the page from Google's cache (click on the little down-pointing arrow to the right of the URL in the list of results), the HTML code will attempt to bring them in. That's why [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#installation) and the other wide-spectrum blockers are a thing.

Comment: see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing

Answer (score 1):

In case you wanted to do this yourself, here is one solution that I came up with to the problem of quickly searching every law ever enacted by the U.S. Congress. These laws are in more than 32GB of PDF files, which you can download for free from [here](https://www.loc.gov/collections/united-states-statutes-at-large/about-this-collection/) and [there](https://www.govinfo.gov/app/collection/statute) on the Internet.

For more than 150 PDF files that I downloaded, I used the naming convention of V<volume>[C<congress>[S<session>]]Y<year>[<description>].pdf. Here's some examples of how my PDF files were named, whitespace and all.

```bash
V1C1Y1789-1791.pdf
V6Y1789-1845 Private Laws and Resolutions.pdf
V7Y1789-1845 Indian Treaties.pdf
V50C75S1Y1937.pdf
V51C75S2Y1937.pdf
V52C75S3Y1938.pdf
V53C76S1Y1939.pdf
V54C76S2-3Y1939-1941.pdf
```

Then I made the following directories to hold the PDF files and their text representations (to be used for fast searching) that I was going to create. I placed all the downloaded PDFs in the first, Originals, directory.

```bash
~/Documents/Books/Laws/Originals/
~/Documents/Books/Laws/PDF/
~/Documents/Books/Laws/Text/
```

The first problem I encountered was that, for the volumes before number 65, the (selectable) text in the PDF files was poorly constructed: often out of order and jumbled around. (I initially discovered this when using a [pdfgrep](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pdfgrep) tool.) This problem made the text almost impossible to search through. However, the images of the PDF files seemed quite reasonable.

Using [brew](https://brew.sh), I installed the [ocrmypdf](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ocrmypdf) tool ("brew install ocrmypdf") to improve the [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) text layer on those problematic PDF files. It worked very well.

To get around some apparent limitations of xargs (long command lines halted file substitutions) and zargs (file substitution halted after a pipe, a redirect, or the first substitution in a string), I had created the following [Zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) function, which I used to mass execute ocrmypdf on 92 PDF files.

```bash
# Make a function to execute a string of shell code in the first argument on
# one or more files specified in the remaining arguments. Every specification
# of $F in the string will be replaced with the current file. If the last
# argument is "test," show each command before asking the user to execute it.
#
#     XonFs <command_string> <file_or_directory>... [test]
#
XonFs()
    {

    # If the last argument is a test, identify and remove it.
    #
    local testing
    if [[ ${argv[-1]} == "test" ]]
        then
        testing=1
        unset -v 'argv[-1]'
        fi

    # Get a list of files, from each argument after the first one, and sort
    # the list like the Finder does. The IFS setting makes the output of the
    # sort command be separated by newlines, instead of by whitespace.
    #
    local F IFS=$'\n' answer=""
    local files=($(sort -Vi <<<"${argv[2,-1]}"))

    # Execute the command for each file. But if we are testing, show the
    # command that will be executed before asking the user for permission to
    # do so.
    #
    for F in $files
        do

        # If this is a test, show the user the command that we will execute,
        # using the current filename. Then ask the user if they want execute
        # the command or not, or just quit the script. If this is not a test,
        # execute the command.
        #
        if (( $testing ))
            then

            # Separate each file execution with a newline. Show the first
            # argument to the function, the command that can be executed, with
            # the f variable expanded as the current file. Then, ask the user
            # whether the command should be executed.
            #
            [[ -n $answer ]] && print
            printf "%s\n" "${(e)1}"
            read -ks "answer?EXECUTE? y/n/q [no] "

            # Report what the user's answer is interpreted to be, and do what
            # they want.
            #
            if [[ "$answer" == [yY] ]]
                then
                print "Yes."
                eval $1
            elif [[ "$answer" == [qQ] ]]
                then
                print "Quit."
                break
            else
                answer="n"
                print "No."
                fi
        else
            eval $1
            fi
        done
    }
```

Thus, I used the following shell commands to put the best versions of the PDF files in the PDF directory. (It took about a day on my computer to complete the ocrmypdf conversions.) During the conversions, I also had text files created from the converted PDF files and placed in the Originals directory.

```bash
cd ~/Documents/Books/Laws/Originals/
cp V{65..128}[YC]*.pdf ../PDF
XonFs 'print "$F"; ocrmypdf -f --sidecar "${F:r}.txt" "$F" "../PDF/$F"; print;' V{1..64}[YC]*.pdf
```

I then used pdftotext to create the text file versions of the original (unconverted) PDF files, as follows. If I remember correctly, the pdftotext tool is installed automatically with the installation of pdfgrep ("brew install pdfgrep").

```bash
XonFs 'print "$F"; pdftotext "$F" "${F:r}.txt";' V{65..128}[YC]*.pdf
```

Next, I created easily and quickly searchable versions of all the text files (direct conversions of the PDF files) and placed these new versions of the text files in the Text directory with the following command.

```bash
XonFs 'print "$F"; cat "$F" | tr -cds "[:space:][:alnum:]\!\$%&,.:;?" "\!\$%&,.:;?" | tr -s "\n" "=" | tr "\f" "_" | tr -s "[:space:]" " " | sed -E -e "s/ ?& ?/ and /g" -e '"'s/[ =]*_[ =]*/\\'$'\n/g' -e 's/( ?= ?)+/\\'$'\t/g'"' > "../Text/$F";' *.txt
```

(Ok, tr and sed commands look crazy, but they basically do the following. Delete everything except certain characters and remove some of their redundancies, change all newlines to =, change each formfeed to _, change all whitespace to " ", and change each "&" into "and", change each _ to newline, and change each = to tab. Thus, in the new versions of the text files, a lot of extraneous characters are removed or reduced, newlines separate pages, and tabs represent newlines. Unfortunately, sed seems to require tricky escaping of characters like \n and \t in sed replacement specifications.)

The below is the zsh code for a tool I created called greplaw (and a supporting function called error). Since I will be using this tool a lot, I placed this code in my ~/.zshenv file.

```bash
# Provide a function to print an error message for the current executor, which
# is identified by the first argument. The second argument, if not null, is a
# custom error message to print. If the third argument exists and is neither
# zero nor null, the script is exited, but only to the prompt if there is one.
# The fourth argument, if present, is the current linenumber to report in the
# error message.
#
# Usage:
#     error [executor [messageString [exitIndicator [lineNumber]]]]
# 
# Examples:
#     error greplaw
#     error greplaw "" 1
#     error greplaw "No text files found" 0 $LINENO
#     error greplaw "No pdf files found" "" $LINENO
#     error greplaw "No files found" x $LINENO
#     error greplaw HELL eject $LINENO
#
error()
    {
    print ${1:-"Script"}": "${4:+"Line $4: "}"Error: "${2:-"Uknown"} 1>&2
    [[ $3 =~ '^0*$' ]] || { ${missing_variable_ejector:?} } 2>/dev/null
    }


# Function to grep through law files: see usage below or execute with -h.
#
greplaw()
    {

    # Provide a function to print an error message for the current executor.
    # If the user did not include any arguments, give the user a little help.
    #
    local executor=$( basename $0 )
    local err() {error $executor $*}
    (( $# )) || 1="-h"

    # Create variables with any defaults that we have. The color and no color
    # variables are for coloring the extra output that this script outputs
    # beyond what grep does.
    #
    local lawFileFilter=() contextLines=1 maxFileMatches=5 grepOutput=1
    local maxPageMatches=5 quiet=0 c="%B%F{cyan}" nc="%f%b" grep="pcregrep"
    local grepOptions=(-M -i --color) fileGrepOptions=(-M -n -i)

    # Print out the usage for the greplaw function roughly in the fashion of a
    # man page, with color and bolding. The output of this function should be
    # sent to a print -P command.
    #
    local help()
        {

        # Make some local variables to make the description more readable in
        # the below string. However, insert the codes for bold and color as
        # appropriate.
        #
        local func="%B%F{red}$executor%f%b" name synopsis description examples
        local c f g h l o p q number pattern option

        # Mass declare our variables for usage categories, function flags, and
        # function argument types. Use the man page standards for formatting
        # the text in these variables.
        #
        for var in name synopsis description examples
            declare $var="%B%F{red}"${(U)var}"%f%b"
        for var in c f g h l o p q
            declare $var="%B%F{red}-"$var"%f%b"
        for var in number pattern option
            declare $var="%U"$var"%u"

        # Print the usage for the function, using our easier to use and read
        # variables.
        #
        cat <<greplawUsage
$name
    $func

$synopsis
    $func [$c $number] [$f $number] [$g] [$h] [$l $pattern]... [$o $option]...
        [$p $number] [$q] $pattern...

$description
    This function searches law files with a regular expression, which is
    specified as one or more arguments. If more than one argument is provided,
    they are joined, with a pattern of whitespace, into a singular expression.
    The searches are done without regard to case or whitespace, including line
    and page breaks. The output of this function is the path of each law file
    the expression is found in, including the PDF page as well as the results
    of the $grep. If just a page is reported without any $grep results,
    the match begins on that page and continues to the next one.

    The following options are available:

        $c $number
           Context of $number lines around each match shown. Default is 1.
        $f $number
           File matches maximum is $number. Default is 5. Infinite is -1.
        $g
           Grep output is omitted
        $h
           Help message is merely printed.
        $l $pattern
           Law file regex $pattern will be added as a filename filter.
        $o $option
           Option $option added to the final $grep execution, for output.
        $p $number
           Page matches maximum is $number. Default is 5. Infinite is -1.
        $q
           Quiet file and page information: information not from $grep.

$examples
        $func bureau of investigation
        $func $o --color=always congress has not | less -r
        $func $l " " $l Law congress
greplawUsage
        }

    # Update our defaulted variables according to the supplied arguments,
    # until an argument is not understood. If an agument looks invalid,
    # complain and eject. Add each law file filter to an array.
    #
    while (( $# ))
        do
        case $1 in
            (-[Cc]*)
                [[ $2 =~ '^[0-9]+$' ]] || err "Bad $1 argument: $2" eject
                contextLines=$2
                shift 2;;
            (-f*)
                [[ $2 =~ '^-?[0-9]+$' ]] || err "Bad $1 argument: $2" eject
                maxFileMatches=$2
                shift 2;;
            (-g*)
                grepOutput=0
                shift;;
            (-h*|--h*)
                print -P "$( help )"
                return;;
            (-l*)
                lawFileFilter+=$2
                shift 2;;
            (-o*)
                grepOptions+=$2
                shift 2;;
            (-p*)
                [[ $2 =~ '^-?[0-9]+$' ]] || err "Bad $1 argument: $2" eject
                maxPageMatches=$2
                shift 2;;
            (-q*)
                quiet=1
                shift;;
            (*)
                break;;
            esac
        done

    # If the user specified that the script and that grep has no output, then
    # we will give no output at all, so just eject with an error. Also, make
    # sure we have remaining arguments to assemble the search pattern with.
    # Assemble it by joining them with the only allowable whitespace in the
    # text files: a space, a tab (which represents a newline), or a newline
    # (which prepresents a new PDF page).
    #
    (( $quiet && ! $grepOutput )) && err "No grep output and quiet: nothing" x
    (( $# )) || err "No pattern supplied to grep law files with" eject
    local pattern=${(j:[ \t\n]:)argv[1,-1]}

    # Quickly seachable text files are searched as representatives of the
    # actual PDF law files. Define our PDF and text directories. Note that to
    # expand the home directory specification, no quotes can be used.
    #
    local pdfDirectory=~/Documents/Books/Laws/PDF
    local textDirectory=${pdfDirectory:h}"/Text"

    # Get a list of the text files, without their directory specifications,
    # sorted like the Finder would: this makes the file in order of when the
    # laws were created. The IFS setting separates the output of the sort
    # command by newlines, instead of by whitespace.
    #
    local filter fileName fileMatches=0 IFS=$'\n'
    local files=( $textDirectory/*.txt )
    local fileNames=( $( sort -Vi <<<${files:t} ) )
    [[ $#files -gt 1 ]] || err "No text files found" eject $LINENO

    # Repeatedly filter the fileNames for each of the law file filters that
    # were passed in.
    #
    for filter in $lawFileFilter
        fileNames=( $( grep $filter <<<"${fileNames}" ) )
    [[ $#fileNames -gt 0 ]] || err "All law files were filtered out" eject

    # For each filename, search for pattern matches. If there are any, report
    # the corresponding PDF file, the page numbers and lines of the match.
    #
    for fileName in $fileNames
        do

        # Do a case-insensitive, multiline grep of the current file for the
        # search pattern. In the grep, have each line prepended with the line
        # number, which represents the PDF page number.
        #
        local pages=() page="" pageMatches=0
        local file=$textDirectory"/"$fileName
        pages=( $( $grep $fileGrepOptions -e $pattern $file ) )

        # If the grep found nothing, move on to the next file. Otherwise, if
        # the maximum file matches has been defined and has been exeeded, then
        # stop processing files.
        #
        if [[ $#pages -eq 0 ]]
            then
            continue
        elif [[ ++fileMatches -gt $maxFileMatches && $maxFileMatches -gt 0 ]]
            then
            break
            fi

        # For each page with a match, print the page number and the matching
        # lines in the page.
        #
        for page in $pages
            do

            # If there have been no previous page matches in the current file,
            # identify the corresponding PDF file that the matches, in theory,
            # come from.
            #
            if [[ ++pageMatches -eq 1 ]]
                then

                # Put a blank line between matches for each file, unless
                # either minimum output is requested or page matches are not
                # reported.
                #
                if [[ $fileMatches -ne 1 && $pageMatches -ne 0
                    && $maxPageMatches -ne 0 ]]
                    then
                    (( $quiet )) || print
                    fi

                # Identify and print in color the full location of the PDF
                # file (prepended with an open command for easy access),
                # unless minimum output is requested.
                #
                local pdfFile=$pdfDirectory"/"${fileName:r}".pdf"
                (( $quiet )) || print -P $c"open "$pdfFile$nc
                fi

            # If the maximum pages matches has been defined and has been
            # exeeded, stop processing pages for the current file.
            #
            if [[ $maxPageMatches -gt 0 && $pageMatches -gt $maxPageMatches ]]
                then
                break
                fi

            # Extract and remove the page number specification (an initial
            # number before a colon) from the grep output for the page. Then
            # extract the lines of the page: tabs are decoded as newlines.
            #
            local pageNumber=${page%%:*}
            page=${page#*:}
            local lines=( $( tr '\t' '\n' <<<$page ) )

            # Print the PDF page number in yellow. Then grep the lines of the
            # page that we have, matching possibly multiple lines without
            # regard to case. And have any grep output use color and a line
            # before and after the match, for context.
            #
            (( $quiet )) || print -P $c"Page "$pageNumber$nc
            if (( $grepOutput ))
                then
                $grep -C $contextLines -e $pattern $grepOptions <<<$lines
                fi
            done
        done
    }
```

Yes, if I had to do it again, I would have used Perl...

Here's the usage for greplaw, as a zsh shell function. It's a surprisingly fast search tool.

```
NAME
    greplaw

SYNOPSIS
    greplaw [-c number] [-f number] [-g] [-h] [-l pattern]... [-o option]...
        [-p number] [-q] pattern...

DESCRIPTION
    This function searches law files with a regular expression, which is
    specified as one or more arguments. If more than one argument is provided,
    they are joined, with a pattern of whitespace, into a singular expression.
    The searches are done without regard to case or whitespace, including line
    and page breaks. The output of this function is the path of each law file
    the expression is found in, including the PDF page as well as the results
    of the pcregrep. If just a page is reported without any pcregrep results,
    the match begins on that page and continues to the next one.

    The following options are available:

        -c number
           Context of number lines around each match shown. Default is 1.
        -f number
           File matches maximum is number. Default is 5. Infinite is -1.
        -g
           Grep output is omitted
        -h
           Help message is merely printed.
        -l pattern
           Law file regex pattern will be added as a filename filter.
        -o option
           Option option added to the final pcregrep execution, for output.
        -p number
           Page matches maximum is number. Default is 5. Infinite is -1.
        -q
           Quiet file and page information: information not from pcregrep.

EXAMPLES
        greplaw bureau of investigation
        greplaw -o --color=always congress has not | less -r
        greplaw -l " " -l Law congress
```

That'll do it... (If I remembered everything correctly and didn't do any typos...)